# How do I get posts that have a thumbnail in WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

I want to grab the 5 most recent posts that have thumbnails.

Comment: Improve your question: What have you tried already? Where did you get stuck? Which errors did you see?

Comment: @toscho I had no idea how to do the query Ryan outlined below with the meta_query. This was really all the information I could supply with the question when I wrote it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be able to call posts with a featured image with the following code:

```
$thumbs = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'meta_query' => array(array('key' => '_thumbnail_id')) 
);
$query = new WP_Query($thumbs);
```

The code checks each post for the custom field _thumbnail_id, which is where the thumbnail image is stored.