# Display only posts with thumbnail using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, thumbnails

I'm having hard times with showing only posts which have featured images using the loop. My PHP level is basic and any help will be really useful.

So basically this is my original code :

```
if( have_posts() ) { 
    while( have_posts() ) { 
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'inc/template-parts/content', $post_layout );
        // and some other stuff
    }
}
```

I tried the advice from this thread  - [How do I check if a post has a post thumbnail in `WP_Query`?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45909/how-do-i-check-if-a-post-has-a-post-thumbnail-in-wp-query)
But without any success. When I implement the code all posts disappear from the front page.

This is the code I tried:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $thumbs );
$thumbs = array(
    'meta_query' => array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id' ) 
);
if( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    while( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'inc/template-parts/content', $post_layout );
    } 
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated! 
Regards

Comment: Okay thanks once again for your time and advices, much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define your arguments **before** you pass them to `WP_Query`, not after. Also, your `meta_query` should be an array of an array, not just an array

This

```
 $query = new WP_Query($thumbs);
 $thumbs = array(
        'meta_query' => array('key' => '_thumbnail_id') 
 );
```

should look like this

```
 $thumbs = array(
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
        ) 
    )
 );

 $query = new WP_Query($thumbs);
```

### EDIT

Just a few extra notes

- Make sure to reset postdata after a custom query. Just add `wp_reset_postdata();` before you close your `if` statement and just after closing your `while` statement
- I believe that a custom query might not be necessary here. If I read your question correctly, you can simply use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query. You shouldn't use a custom query just because you want to alter the main query

Comment: I also wonder if OP has `$post_layout` defined

Comment: Apparently he has if I read the question correctly :-) @birgire

Comment: my thought here was that (in addition to your correction) if all posts disappeared for him, then the problem might be a wrong template path (like undefined `$post_layout`) or syntax error, because his syntax-wrong meta query would just results in a default query without any meta query. just wondering ;-)

Comment: If you don't pass anything to `WP_Query`, then you get an empty object. Remember, the arguments are only defined after doing the query :-) @birgire

Comment: hehe you're absolutely correct, I was just babbling, too early in the morning  ;-)

Comment: Hahaha @birgire It is weekend after all.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel little weird now, almost retarded... for not noticing this. This solved the issue but now Im getting infinite loop of all posts in random order. Any suggestion how to limit them ?

Comment: I checked the thread and inserted an ordering by meta key but Im still getting duplicates. I tried few other ordering options but they dont seem to fix the problem. I will try to debug it, it's strange issue. I will update the first post with rest ot the code, it may help.Regards

Answer (score 0):

Another approch for woocommerce products:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'products_with_thumbs', 10);
```

`function products_with_thumbs()
{
    return array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array('key' => '_thumbnail_id',
        'compare' => '>',
        'value' => '0')
    );
}`